# Find a string with regex and replace with some random String with SED

Tags: linux, sed

I have a regular expression  `MyRegularExpression` , and i want to replace it with xxxxxxxxxabc with a,b,c are some random number. How can i do it with `sed` ?

Answer (score 1):

The string replacement is easy. Generating random numbers is *probably* possible but will be horrendous to read and virtually impossible to maintain (just have a look through some of the [officially sanctioned sample scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Examples.html#Examples)).

I would do something like

```
replacement="xxxxx$(printf "%05d" $RANDOM | cut -c 3-5)"
sed 's/MyRegularExpression/'"$replacement/"
```

That's a bit of an ugly mess of quotes, but it's probably better that escaping all the special chars in the regex that would be affected by using double quotes for the whole sed body.

---

Update, based on your comment:

```
perl -pe 's{my_regex}{ sprintf "xxxxx%03d", int(1000*rand()) }ge' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat sample.py
def f1(a,b,c):
    x = a + b + c
    return x

def f2(a,b):
    x = a + b
    return x

$ perl -pe 's{def|return}{ sprintf "%s%03d", uc($&), int(1000*rand()) }ge' sample.py
DEF905 f1(a,b,c):
    x = a + b + c
    RETURN771 x

DEF146 f2(a,b):
    x = a + b
    RETURN199 x
```

Comment: At first thanks for your answer, what if i want to change the random number every time it finds a match, is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Not with sed. I'd use perl.